# How to best design a class that might contain null object

Tags: c#

I'm about to design a class that more often then not will contain a reference to a `Null` value. It reminded me of nullable `Datetime` which has a boolean value to indicate if there is an actual value stored.

```
        DateTime? dt = new DateTime?();
        if(dt.HasValue)
        {
            //DoStuff
        }
```

Is it a good coding practice to design a class as follows?

```
class Computer
{
    public string Name;
    public string ID;
    //...
    public bool IsHiveMind;
    public HiveMindInfo RegInfo;
}
class HiveMindInfo
{
    string SecretLocation;
    int BaudRate;
    int Port;
}
```

...and to use it...

```
Computer aComputer = GetComputer(...);
if(aComputer.IsHiveMind)
{
    Network.DoHostileTakeOver(aComputer); //!
}
```

Comment: Who sets the 'IsHiveMind'? you should modify it to `public bool IsHiveMind{get; private set;}` first.

Answer (score 1):

How about this code below?
It seems you can remove IsHiveMind variable since HiveMindInfo variable has the same meaning by checking its null or not.

```
  class Computer
  {
    public string Name;
    public string ID;

    public HiveMindInfo RegInfo;
  }

  class HiveMindInfo
  {
    string SecretLocation;
    int BaudRate;
    int Port;
  }

  Computer aComputer = GetComputer(...);

  if (aComputer != null && aComputer.RegInfo != null)
  {
    Network.DoHostileTakeOver(aComputer);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, you could implement the code as proposed.

An alternative would be to consider the following design patterns:

- [Proxy Design Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/proxy-design-pattern%20%22DoFactory.com:%20Proxy%20Design%20Pattern)
- [Strategy Design Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/strategy-design-pattern)

#### Sample Code

```
    interface ITakeOverStrategy
    {
       void Execute();
    }

    class KevinFlynnHackerStrategy : ITakeOverStrategy
    {
        public void Execute()
        {
            // a nod to Tron
        }
    }

    class NeoHackerStrategy: ITakeOverStrategy
    {
        private readonly HiveMindInfo _hiveMindInfo;

        public NeoHackerStrategy(HiveMindInfo info)
        {
           _hiveMindInfo = info;
        }
        public void Execute()
        {
            // Mr. Anderson!
        }
    }

    // This is a surrogate class.
    // ... The value returned by String.Empty is often used as a surrogate.
    class IdleStrategy : ITakeOverStrategy
    {
        public void Execute()
        {
            // do nothing
        }
    }

    class Computer
    {
        private readonly ITakeOverStrategy _takeoverStrategy ;

        public Computer(ITakeOverStrategy strategy)
        {
            _takeoverStrategy = strategy;
        }

        public Subjugate()
        {
            // insert epic code here
            _takeoverStrategy.Execute();
        }
     }
```

Then somewhere in your code you create an instance of `Computer` with the appropriate strategy:

```
var info = new HiveMindInfo();
// update instance parameters

var computer = new Computer(new NeoHackerStrategy(info));
computer.Subjugate();
```

## UPDATES

#### August 13th, 2015 @ 10:13 EST

My comment about structs is not within the scope of the original question, and has been removed:

*If your classes are only going to contain fields*/*properties then I would consider converting them into struct.*

Comment: "If your classes are only going to contain fields/properties then I would consider converting them into struct" - what's your thinking behind this. I'm always a little unsure when I should use structs and when not. I don't think I've ever come across this logic before though.

Comment: Honestly, when I have a class with properties, and no methods... then my next thought is: *is this a good candidate for a struct*. Every implementation is different, so I would suggest reading the following: [When do you use a struct instead of a class?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/92339/when-do-you-use-a-struct-instead-of-a-class) and [MSDN: Choosing Between Class and Struct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Well that doesn't seem to suggest he should be using structs at all... The fact his classes have strings mean "It has an instance size under 16 bytes" won't be satisfied. Not is it immutable. Certainly nothing there seems to suggest lack of methods as a requisite to use a struct.

Comment: @Chris: I was working under the assumption that the fields/properties in the example were just placeholders to provide context for David's question.  The only point I was trying to make was: if you are going to have a class with just fields/properties...  then you may wish to consider using a struct.  To your point, the data structure you choose will be dependent on it's content.  Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score -2):

Just add ? to your object:

```
class Computer
{
    public string Name;
    public string ID;
    //...
    public HiveMindInfo? RegInfo;
}
struct HiveMindInfo
{
    string SecretLocation;
    int BaudRate;
    int Port;
}
```

And then check it exactly as you did with datetime:

```
Computer aComputer = GetComputer(...);
if (aComputer.RegInfo.HasValue)
{ 
     // Do something 
}
```

Comment: But do you think it is a good design? Versus if(aComputer.RegInfo != null)

Comment: You could only do this if HiveMindInfo were a `struct`. And you probably do not want this. The whole point of a reference class is that it *can* be null without external helper classes.

Comment: you are right.. So David need to decide if he wants to covnert his class to struct or use an boolean property